# Odd website tracking issue, getting discordant results

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics, web-analytics

On one of our client sites, we track conversion using both Google Analytics [events tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) and DoubleClick [Floodlight tags](http://support.google.com/dfa/partner/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=28820&guide=28818&page=guide.cs), for a handful of reasons. The tracking tags come from the same .Net WebControl, so the numbers should sync up.

The code looks like this (where I've added line-wrapping in the script includes, the `pageTracker._trackEvent` line and in the `iframe` URL for legibility, as well as combining code from a couple of source files):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=
    Page.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https://ssl." : "http://www."
    %>google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("<%= GoogleAnalyticsID %>");
    pageTracker._setDomainName("<%= SiteDomain %>");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageTracker._trackEvent('<%= CategoryID %>', '<%= BrochureName %>',
        '<%= MetaData %>');
</script>
<iframe id="floodlightIframe"
  src="https://fls.uk.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=XXXXX123;cat=<%=
  Server.UrlEncode(CategoryID) %>;u4=<%= Server.UrlEncode(BrochureName) %>;u5=<%=
  Server.UrlEncode(MetaData) %>;ord=<%= new Random().Next(1000000000) %>?"
  width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#floodlightIframe').load(function () {
        document.location.replace('<%= RedirectDestination %>');
    });
</script>
<noscript><p><a href="<%= RedirectDestination %>">Please click here
  to continue</a>.</p></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

What's confusing me is that Google Analytics is tracking 813 events on 31 January 2012, across all the possible combinations of `BrochureName` and `MetaData` for the one `CategoryID` I'm currently focussing on. DoubleClick, however are telling me they had 47 hits for that `CategoryID`.

Fwiw, the page is always rendered by SSL and the variables in the code (like `BrochureName`) will always have a value; if the correct value is not passed to the page, a default is set. We have received no complaints that users are not being redirected to `RedirectDestination` so, to our mind, everything should be working as expected — both the `pageTracker._trackEvent` should fire and the iframe HTTP request be sent, then the user should be redirected.

Now it's entirely possible that the third-party is misunderstanding what they're supposed to be sending us and are mailing over a subset of the data we want (which is their equivalent of the 813 GA events). That's what I think is the most likely outcome.

But I just want to sanity-check that I'm not missing some obvious flaw in our code that means that the Floodlight tags (the ones in the `iframe`) will under-report by an order of magnitude.

Comment: It looks like you're comparing events (multiple per user/visit) to visits. How does the 47 number compare to the number of unique visitors to the site?

Comment: The events are what we want to track, but they're only a small part of the site. The site overall had over 6k visits from over 5800 unique visitors on the day in question. But lots of them won't have gone near the part of the site I'm concerned by at the moment.